# Python: Can't start new thread, but have plenty of system resources

Tags: python, multithreading

I am getting `error: can't start new thread` in `threading.py:745` when trying to start a python thread. However, I have plenty of system resources available, so I'm not sure what the problem is. Any insight?

It looks like the entire system has about 4000 threads, far below the system limit:

```
$ # Current Number of Threads:
$ ps -fLA|wc -l
3996
$ # Max system threads
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max 
261270
```

I have plenty of disk space:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G   13M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/sda1        20G  8.5G   11G  46% /
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

As well as RAM, from top:

```
top - 01:10:29 up  1:01,  1 user,  load average: 0.42, 0.80, 1.05
Tasks: 213 total,   2 running, 211 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 12.8 us,  2.1 sy,  0.0 ni, 84.5 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.6 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem : 32683.09+total, 14809.33+free, 13929.25+used, 3944.500
```

Any other resource that would cause this issue?

Comment: How many threads are you launching when you get this error? Try `threading.active_count()`

Comment: I'm only launching one at a time `threading.active_count()` is roughly 150.

Comment: Just a hunch but did you already check out `threading.py:745` to see what needs to happen for it to throw the error? I mean, have you studied the contents of `threading.py` around line 745? Maybe it could give you some clues as to what is happening..

Comment: It calls into a C sub-routine: `_start_new_thread(self.__bootstrap, ())`